# unable to call rest web service from html/javascript with parameter

Tags: java, javascript, html, rest, get

I am new to web service and html/javascript.
I have written one REST web service in java. It accepts the username from the html form and again returns it to the same html page. Which i have displayed using alert() function call.

My web service code is

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

@GET
    @Path("hello/{username}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String ldap(@PathParam("username") String username)
    {
    return username;
    }
}
```

My jsp file is first.jsp  ( pasted the selected code only, so no error regarding html, body tags )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function callservice()
{
        alert("I am in javascript");
        var user = document.getElementById("uid");
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.workspace.first/rest/hello/" + user.value;
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
        alert("after url");
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        alert("after send");
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                alert("In functn");
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }

        }

    }
</script>

    <form style="margin-left:300px" id="f1" method="GET" onsubmit="callservice()" >
            <fieldset style="margin: 50px"> 
            <legend>Login</legend>
                <p>
                User name: <input  type="text" id="uid" name="username"><br>
                <p> 

                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                <p id="qwe"> This HTML</p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

From the first.jsp file i have called the web service. I do the same without any parameter, I return something hardcoded value from the web service, then it works. But i need the parameters passing as i want to authenticate the user.

I think i am doing something wrong in the parameter passing.

When i click on the submit button i can see the url in browser as

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080/de.vogella.workspace.first/first.jsp?username=john
```

and when i test web service as standalone it looks like

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8080/de.vogella.workspace.first/rest/hello

Can anybody please help me to sort it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the javascript is running one ajax call and when that is done the form is being submitted.  Remove the form completely and just have a button and input box to call your javascript.  You should also look into using jquery, if possible.

Look at this link to understand your problem.
[How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Also a tip for debugging use firebug net panel to view the requests that were actually being generated from your code.